# group function in where clause giving error

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, where-clause

```
SELECT
    pro.`Name`,
    pro.idProduct,
    COUNT(DISTINCT pur.idPurchase) AS Sales
FROM
product AS pro
INNER JOIN purchase pur ON pur.idProduct = pro.idProduct
WHERE pro.idUser = '54c26fdac8f5c'
AND COUNT(DISTINCT pur.idPurchase) > '2'
GROUP BY pro.idProduct
```

I am trying to get all products which purchases are greater than 2 so I tried this in where clause to add this group function

```
COUNT(DISTINCT pur.idPurchase) > '2'
```

but I got this error

> Invalid use of group function

Comment: move the aggregate condition COUNT(DISTINCT pur.idPurchase) > 2 to the having clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
pro.`Name`,
pro.idProduct,
COUNT(DISTINCT pur.idPurchase) AS Sales
FROM
product AS pro
INNER JOIN purchase pur ON pur.idProduct = pro.idProduct
WHERE pro.idUser = '54c26fdac8f5c'
GROUP BY pro.`Name`, pro.idProduct
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pur.idPurchase) > '2'
```

Comment: @user3365992:- You are welcome. You can accept the answer if that helped you.(A green tick mark turns green when clicked)